# Adding UIButton to subView

Tags: iphone, ios

When the User taps on the screen a PopUp should appear with a button in it. 
But i don't know why the button isn't shown in the PopUp. Is there a problem because it is a subview in a subview ?

```
-(void) popUpWithX:(int)x andY:(int)y {
    CGRect popUpRect = CGRectMake(x, y, 125, 75);
    popUp = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:popUpRect];
    popUp.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    popUp.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5f;
    popUp.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:popUp];
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
    [button setTitle:@"Click me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [popUp addSubview:button];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Is it possible that the coordinates of the UIButton are wrong ? I am not sure if the coordinate system is from the main view or from the popUp subview.

Comment: The coordinates are from the pop up, not the main view. That's most likely not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button is there, but is not visible because of maskToBounds set to YES. Try it just set to NO just for testing purposes. Then fix your x, y coordinates for button.

Answer (score 2):

If the button is going to be a subview of a subview, then you need to add the button prior to adding the view containing it to the main view....i.e. you're adding the button too late.

```
//Move this line to the end of the block
[self.view addSubview:popUp];//call this after you add your subViews to popUp
```

Comment: I tested this, and it didn't fix the problem.